# How to justify a paragraph in Itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a `pdfptable` with 3 columns, and a `pdfpcell` (with `colspan` 3) , and inside this `pdfpcell` I have a paragraph and I need to show it in PDF with `justified` alignment .

```
PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(3);
tbl.WidthPercentage = 100;

string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
"Maecenas diam nulla, aliquam eget porttitor sit amet, blandit quis nisi." +
"Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum eu eros elit. Nullam laoreet, elit ac tincidunt " +
"convallis, urna dui semper nisi, et imperdiet orci sem quis ante. Aliquam " +
"ut velit vitae massa aliquet malesuada. Quisque a mauris ante. Nam dolor " +
"leo, aliquam congue blandit quis, convallis non mi.";

PdfPCell cellText = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text,arial12blackBold));
```

cellText.colspan = 3;

```
tbl.AddCell(cellText);
```

The font was created earlier and the document generation after this block are normal. I only need to know how to set this paragraph or this cell to show justified-aligned the string .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED
```

or

```
PdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL
```